# Maximum number of web parts/web part zones per page? (Microsoft SharePoint 2007)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I've already found the max number of web parts per page:

- Customizable - in web.config file, `<configuration><SharePoint><WebPartLimits MaxZoneParts="XX" />`
- 50 (default) - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx
- 100 (recommended max) - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287743.aspx

However, I've been unable to find:

- the maximum number of web parts
  per web part zone
- the maximum number of web part
  zones per page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out this article:

http://aberkut.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/the-maximum-number-of-web-parts-for-all-zones-on-this-page-has-been-exceeded-error/

Wasn't easy to find, but it might help. Looks like the default limit it 50.

Answer (score 1):

These are theoreticall limits.

Everytime you add an extra webpart to a page the load time increases. In my experiance the site will become too slow long before you hit these limits.

Comment: Yeah, but I still want to know what the limit is. Actually it'd be even more useful to know where the limit is configured (like I found for web parts per page), so then I can administrate those limits.